# How to open custom type from plsql on php?

Tags: php, database, oracle, plsql, oci8

I have created a type on Oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE  myType as object (
id number,rol varchar(16) );​
```

Then I have this function that returns an object of type myType

```
create or replace FUNCTION myFunction(...) RETURN myType IS
.... 
END;
```

On plsql I can access the attributes of the returned object just doing this:

```
var := myFunction(...);
dbms_output.put_line(var.rol);
```

But how can I have access to the object attributes from php using OCI8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a type of that object to be able to return it as a table.

```
CREATE TYPE tableType AS TABLE OF myType
```

Then, using Oracle's table() function you can handle the output as a normal select on PHP

```
select *
from   table(myFunction(...))
```

simple, huh? :)

(edited as requested for completeness)

Comment: thanks it works, just edit your answer and add that I need to create a table type:
CREATE TYPE tableType IS TABLE OF myType, and that I just have to handle the select as a normal query on PHP

Comment: Also I can just use a sys_refcursor, and use OCI_B_CURSOR, right?